# UITapGesture Selector for UILabel issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I added tapGesture for self.view and UILabel (subview of mainView), each performs different selectors.

But the only main view tapGesture is being called and label tapgesture is not being called. How it is handled?

Here is the code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer  *tapGesForSelf = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGesForSelf:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesForSelf];


UITapGestureRecognizer *tapLblClick = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGesForLbl:)];
[lbl addGestureRecognizer:tapLblClick];
```

For two selectors only one method is called tapGesForSelf.
Here lbl is the subview of self.view.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Instead of a label use a UIButton and define its selector action.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get UILabel to respond to tap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154340/how-to-get-uilabel-to-respond-to-tap)

Comment: Have you enabled user interaction of your label??

Comment: Yes its enabled.

Comment: what the frame or yiur label

Comment: It is within the main view.

Comment: It might be one of the possibility that the user interaction of your MainView is disabled.

Comment: Add these lines    tapGesForSelf.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapLblClick.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_lbl setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    UITapGestureRecognizer  *tapGesForSelf = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGesForSelf:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesForSelf];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapLblClick = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGesForLbl:)];
    [_lbl addGestureRecognizer:tapLblClick];
    [tapGesForSelf requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapLblClick];
}
- (void)tapGesForSelf:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    NSLog(@"self");
}
- (void)tapGesForLbl:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    NSLog(@"label");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I post answer for your question now once I tried and it worked well.

First see the label in design.I set label text as "Tap Me"

[image]

Now I set the code for view and label

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  //TapGesture for Label
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapLabel = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(actionTapLabel:)];
  tapLabel.delegate = self;
  tapLabel.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
  lblTapMe.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  [lblTapMe addGestureRecognizer:tapLabel];

  //TapGesture for View
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapMainView = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(actionTapMainView:)];
  tapMainView.delegate = self;
  tapMainView.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapMainView];
}

//Action method for Label
-(void)actionTapLabel:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureOnLabel{
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)gestureOnLabel.view;
    NSLog(@"Lable text is - %@",label.text);
}

//Action method for View
-(void)actionTapMainView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureOnMainView{
    NSLog(@"The Main view is tapped");
}
```

Output Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please setUserInteractionEnabled:YES for interact the TapGesture

```
[lbl setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```